# MongoDB Schema optimization for contacts

Tags: mongodb

I am storing my contacts in mongodb like this but main drawback of this schema is I am not able to store 40k-50k contacts in one document due to limit of 16mb.

I want to change my schema now. So can anyone please suggest me best way to redesign this.

Here is my sample doucument

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c53653451154c6da4623a77"),
    "contacts" : [{
         name:"",
         email:"",
         group:[5c53653451154c6da4623a79]
    }],
    "groups" : [{
         _id: ObjectId("5c53653451154c6da4623a79"),
         group_name:"test"
     }],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you document sample, `contacts` belongs to a `group`.

In that scenario, there are different ways to end up with a better schema:

**1- Document embedding:**

You will have an array of `contacts` inside each `group` document.

collection **groups**:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5c53653451154c6da4623a79"),
    "group_name":"test",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "name":"something",
            "email":"something",
        },         
        {
            "name":"something else",
            "email":"something else",
        }
    ]
}
```

**2- Document referencing:**

You will have two collections - `contacts` and `groups` - and store a group reference inside each `contact`.

collection **contacts**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c53653451154c6da4623a77"),
    "name":"something",
    "email":"something",
    "groups":["5c53653451154c6da4623a79"]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c536s7df9sd7f987d9s7d98"),
    "name":"something else",
    "email":"something else",
    "groups":["5c53653451154c6da4623a79"]
}
```

collection **groups**:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5c53653451154c6da4623a79"),
    "group_name":"test"
}
```

Why are we referencing `group` inside `contact` and not the contrary? Because we probably will have more `contacts` than `groups`. This way we have smaller documents with smaller "reference arrays".

The path you will follow depends a lot on how many `contacts` you have per `group`. If this number is small, I would take the **Document Embedding** approach, for the sake of simplicity and access easiness. If you have a large number of `contacts` per `group`, I would use **Document Reference**, to have smaller documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll go with second because I have more contact per group.